# Bootstrap button dropdowns not working while my example works fine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, button, twitter-bootstrap

I have created an example for bootstrap button drop down :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Button</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/bootstrap.css"/> 
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn btn-success">Action</button>
      <button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="">HI</a></li>
        <li><a href="">BYE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this example is working fine.
But when i have create the same in my rails 3 application drop down is not working. Here is my code: In Application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Accounting-ProfitBooks</title>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'style','custom','report','jquery-ui' %>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'jquery.ui.datepicker' %>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'ui.dropdownchecklist' %>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag "jquery-1.7.2-ui.css" %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.4.2.min", "jquery-1.8.1.ui.min", "jsapi" %>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag "zendesk.css" %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag "zendesk.js" %>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap.css" %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap.js"%>
        <%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap.min.js"%>
        <%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap-dropdown.js"%>
        <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.6.4.min.js',"jquery-1.8.ui.min.js" %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.ui.core.min' %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'ui.dropdownchecklist' %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.ui.widget.min' %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.ui.tabs.min' %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.tipTip.min' %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.ui.datepicker' %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.ui.autocomplete.min' %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.superfish.min' %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.supersubs.min' %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.validate_pack' %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.nyroModal.pack' %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.dataTables.min' %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'nested_form' %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'best_in_place' %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'colortip-1.0-jquery.js'%>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'script.js'%>

            <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
```

and here is my html:

```
<div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn btn-success">Action</button>
      <button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="">HI</a></li>
        <li><a href="">BYE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

I think their is a problem with my jquery but i am unable to track, any help would be thankfull.

Comment: Are you sure that file is `application.js`? If it is, then it's completely wrong. You can't use anything other than pure JavaScript and Sprockets directives in `application.js`.

Comment: woah!!! first of all 'Asset Pipeline' mean anything? why are you calling all the stylesheets individually? *= require_tree . in your application.js file and @depa is correct

Comment: @depa thanks for the comment, it is written wrong here it was application.html.erb file form my layout folder

Comment: Still, there's no reason for you to list your CSS and JS files like that. If you want to list them individually, you can still do that in the asset manifests -- `application.css` and `application.js`

Comment: @depa your are right but i am currently using rails version 3.0.6 , i will do it from now thanks for comment

Answer (score 0):

I have got a solution for this issue, actually, i have some issue with my jquery so i download latest jquery and apply it and it works for me.
Here is my new jquery files files:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

I have included both into application.htm.erb layout file and everything is ok.